# WebAPI 2 routing areas

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5.1

I have an area called "Location" in which there is a controller called "CountryController". I would like to call the GET action using api/location/country. Is there any way to specify Areas in the default route?

Ideally something like

```
routeTemplate: "api/{area}/{controller}/{action}/{id}"
```

Comment: You can directly define it in your WebApiConfig as long as your controller exists in the corresponding namespace. Area is more of a concept for MVC to define it's search range of views, and since APIController doesn't need views, it won't be a problem. If you have issues like two controllers has same name in different area, attribute routing can make your life easier IMO

Comment: Neither api/location/country nor api/country are getting to the resource. I just assumed that it's an area routing issue.

Comment: You have to first create a route and define the `{area}` in your WebApiConfig although you are not going to use that for anything. Otherwise the route will assume your "country" as controller name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to write a custom action selector to achieve selection based on namespaces.

Since it's tough to get right (and get the performance and caching after you do it).

I'd recommend going with attribute routing instead.

Comment: Attribute routing. Thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 0):

Area functionality not available in Asp.Net Web API project, and its harder to maintain with custom way like Namespace based controller.Please visit https://stackoverflow.com/a/34452395/1365663 to get your solution